# Every time I click the button it only adds 50 increments,

Tags: swift, if-statement, nsuserdefaults

When I'm on the simulator and click the button it keeps adding 50. I think it may not be saving "latestTerminationDate", or maybe not pulling it.  Thank you for any help

```
@IBOutlet weak var coalRunButton: UIButton!
var coalMayham = 1


@IBAction func coalRunButton(_ sender: Any) {
   if let buttonPress = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey:  "buttonPress") as? Date,
       let terminationDate = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "latestTerminationDate") as? Date {
       var terminationDuration = buttonPress.timeIntervalSince(terminationDate)
       if terminationDuration >= 86400 {  
           _ = 86400
           do { UserDefaults.standard.set(Date(), forKey: "latestTerminationDate")
                UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
                let dailyCoalAccumulate  = ((Int(terminationDuration)) * coalMayham) + Int(coalPile.text!)!
                coalPile.text = String(dailyCoalAccumulate)
                UserDefaults.standard.set(Data(), forKey:"totalCoal")
           }
       } else  {
         terminationDuration =  50

         UserDefaults.standard.set(Date(), forKey: "latestTerminationDate")
         UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

         let dailyCoalAccumulate  = ((Int(terminationDuration)) * coalMayham) + Int(coalPile.text!)!
         coalPile.text = String(dailyCoalAccumulate)
         UserDefaults.standard.set(Data(), forKey:"totalCoal")

       }
   } else {
      let terminationDuration = 40

      UserDefaults.standard.set(Date(), forKey: "latestTerminationDate")
      UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

      let dailyCoalAccumulate  = ((Int(terminationDuration)) * coalMayham) + Int(coalPile.text!)!
      coalPile.text = String(dailyCoalAccumulate)
      UserDefaults.standard.set(Data(), forKey:"totalCoal")
   }
}
```

Comment: Please, now that you've accepted a very good answer to your issue, could you edit your question title to actually reflect something that may help others? *"...it only adds 50 increments,"* really isn't helping anyone. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code:

```
let terminationDate = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "latestTerminationDate") as? Date
```

Is not returning what you think it does. Because in this line of code:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(Date(), forKey: "latestTerminationDate")
```

the `Date()` you are entering looks like: "2018-10-04 15:30:22 +0000"
which can not be compared to 86400

For that reason:

```
if terminationDuration >= 86400
```

fails and reverts to:

```
 else  {
        terminationDuration =  50
```

---

**EDIT**

**FIX EXAMPLE:**

```
func getMillisecondsNow() -> Int64{
    let currentDate = Date()
    return getMillisecondsFromDate(date: currentDate)
}


func getMillisecondsFromDate(date: Date) -> Int64{
    var d : Int64 = 0
    let interval = date.timeIntervalSince1970
    d = Int64(interval * 1000)

    return d
}

func getTimeDifferenceFromNowInMilliseconds(time: Int64) -> Int64{
    let now = getMillisecondsNow()
    let diff: Int64 = now - time
    return diff
}
```

This will be in milliseconds so you will need to use 86400000 (milliseconds in 24 hrs) instead of 86400 (seconds in 24 hrs)

Now in your code simply use this to save the termination time in Milliseconds:

```
let now = getMillisecondsNow()
UserDefaults.standard.set(now, forKey: "latestTerminationDate")
```

and this code to retrieve and get the time difference in Milliseconds:

```
let terminationTime = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "latestTerminationDate") as? Int64
let timeDiff = getTimeDifferenceFromNowInMilliseconds(time: terminationTime)

if timeDiff >= 86400000 {
}
else {
}
```

Comment: @ barns How can I fix it

Comment: It's supposed to be how many seconds in a 24-hour period.  I don't want them to be able to accumulate more than.

Comment: @sillyJohn :: Updated answer to provide a basis for a solution. This is just a guide line. You will need to put the code in the right places.

Comment: why Milliseconds verse seconds

Comment: because most languages (obj-c, java, swift, c#...) have agreed to provide a reference "time" to the specific date: Jan. 1970 (I forgot the exact date). And these languages provide a built-in method to get the time difference in milliseconds from now to this time. In Swift this is `timeIntervalSince1970()` in java it is `getTimeInMillis()`. If two code bases (Swift and Java) were to call the relevant method at the same time (highly unlikely due to the milliseconds, but..) they would return the same Int64 value!

Comment: @sillyJohn :: notice that you have defined  `let terminationTime = Int64()` which is outside the block. (That is good.) But in the `if ... else` block of code you have added `let terminationTime = ...` in both `if` and `else`  which is overriding the `let terminationTime = Int64()` which is outside the block.  Just remove the `let` so that the `if` block is::  `if (UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "latestTerminationDate") as? Int64) != nil { terminationTime = getMillisecondsNow()
} else { terminationTime = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "latestTerminationDate") as! Int64 } `

Comment: I am still not there, please help. let terminationTime = Int64() if (UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "latestTerminationDate") as? Int64) != nil { let terminationTime = getMillisecondsNow()} else { let terminationTime = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "latestTerminationDate") as! Int64 } let timeDiff = getTimeDifferenceFromNowInMilliseconds(time: terminationTime) let timeDiffernt = Int(timeDiff) let now = getMillisecondsNow() UserDefaults.standard.set (now, forKey: "latestTerminationDate")

Comment: Like I said in the comment above, just remove the `let` from the `let terminationTime = ... ` from the code inside the `if .. else` block. Above the block you must now make `terminationTime` a var --> `var terminationTime: Int64 = -1`

Comment: Thanks but it is not working.  I did delate the "lets"

Comment: @ Barns I do appreciate your help tremendously so far. But for some reason it is not working. When I click the button nothing actually happens

Comment: You need to assign a button action--either programmatically or through the InterfaceBuilder (IB)

Comment: @ barns Sorry I did put this all in a button sorry I didn't show that code, maybe ask new question thank you for your time